# Pandas shift column data upon condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, indexing, multiple-columns

I have `dataframe` which look like this.

```
    Name    Val Rating  
0   ABC     123 B + 
1   DEF     234 B + 
2   567     B-  NaN
3   GHI     890 D
```

but instead I want to shift the data by checking `(col['Name'])` to next column `(col['Val'])` and successively shifting. Also if the shifting happens change the row `index` value. I want the following `dataframe` as output.

```
    Name    Val Rating  
0   ABC     123 B + 
1   DEF     234 B + 
    NaN     567 B - 
2   GHI     890 D
```

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: you should be dealing with this upstream and sanitising the inputs before they're put in a dataframe

Comment: In pandas need always index values, so what is reason for remove it?

Comment: What do you want the new index value to be?

Comment: @aydow but there may be presence of multi-row data is well. As in here `DEF` is having 2 values '234' & '567'. And I don't have access to inputs before dataframe.

Comment: @jezrael. As in table if there is value not related to `Name` and have values then assumption is that `Name` above has taken multiple `val` data.

Comment: @abhi1610 - sorry, dont understand. Is not possible create boolean mask by check non numeric in `Name` column?

Comment: @jezrael It can be done. But this is the partial solution, I want also the index to be change. According to `'Name'` column values. Say it if there is `'567'` value in `1st column` then i have to change the index for next record. I don't know if there is possibility or not.

Comment: @abhi1610 - NOt easy, but possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can shift rows by boolean mask:

```
mask = pd.to_numeric(df['Name'], errors='coerce').notnull()
df[mask] = df[mask].shift(axis=1)
print (df)
  Name  Val Rating
0  ABC  123    B +
1  DEF  234    B +
2  NaN  567     B-
3  GHI  890      D
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df['Name'], errors='coerce'))
0      NaN
1      NaN
2    567.0
3      NaN
Name: Name, dtype: float64
```

If really need replace index values to `empty` strings is possible create helper `Series` and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html).

But this is not recommended because performance problem and possible some function with this index should failed.

```
i = df.index[~mask]
df.index = pd.Series(range(len(i)), index=i).reindex(df.index, fill_value='')
print (df)
  Name  Val Rating
0  ABC  123    B +
1  DEF  234    B +
   NaN  567     B-
2  GHI  890      D
```

Comment: @abhi1610 - Sure, try convert column to numeric and if failed, create NaNs.

Comment: @abhi1610 - Added index - for shifted values are used empty strings, because each row need index by design.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
df[df['Rating'].isnull()]=df[df['Rating'].isnull()].shift(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Name  Val Rating
0  ABC  123    B +
1  DEF  234    B +
2  NaN  567     B-
3  GHI  890      D
```

#### Edit:

```
df[df['Rating'].isnull()|df['Name'].isnull()]=df[df['Rating'].isnull()|df['Name'].isnull()].shift(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But @jezrael's answer also mitigate index issue too, so consider his solution as the answer. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 1):

Using `isdigit`:

```
df[df['Name'].str.isdigit()] = df[df['Name'].str.isdigit()].shift(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Val Rating
0  ABC  123      B +
1  DEF  234      B +
2  NaN  567      B-
3  GHI  890      D
```

Answer (score -2):

## first define a function:

```
import numpy as np

def f1(row):
    if not row.rating:
         row.Rating = row.val
         row.val = row.Name
         row.Name = np.NaN
```

## then use `pandas.DataFrame.apply`:

```
df.apply(f1,axis=1)
```

Comment: Why not just use the `.shift()` function instead of doing what you do