# python, move the row rightward when there is none and fill missing by back filling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data:

```
         year      all deceased living   data
0        2018    7,107    4,394  2,713   None
1        2017   16,478   10,286  6,192   None
2        2016   15,944    9,971  5,973   None
3 Alabama    To Date        5,926   3,471   2,455 
124      1990       85       49     36   None
125      1989       80       57     23   None
126      1988       86       68     18   None
127  Arkansas  To Date    2,963  1,931  1,032
128      1989       16       12      4   None
129      1988       16       11      5   None
```

I want to detect rows with the data=None, move those rows rightward for one column, leaving the first column missing, and fill it by backward filling.

Result:

```
    state     year      all deceased living   
0   None     2018    7,107    4,394  2,713   
1   None     2017   16,478   10,286  6,192   
2   None     2016   15,944    9,971  5,973   
3 Alabama    To Date        5,926   3,471   2,455 
124 Alabama     1990       85       49     36   
125 Alabama     1989       80       57     23   
126 Alabama     1988       86       68     18   
127 Arkansas  To Date    2,963  1,931  1,032
128 Arkansas     1989       16       12      4   
129 Arkansas     1988       16       11      5
```

At last I will delete rows with year=To Date, making it a formal dataset.

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of or at least related to [Pandas shift column data upon condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51184346/pandas-shift-column-data-upon-condition/51184523#51184523)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps involved here. The easiest way, in my opinion, is to define your `state` series first, drop the sub-heading rows next, and then as a final step convert appropriate columns to numeric.

```
import numpy as np
import locale

# set locale, for converting strings with commas to integers
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')

# define state and front fill
df['state'] = np.where(pd.to_numeric(df['year'], errors='coerce').isnull(),
                       df['year'], np.nan)
df['state'] = df['state'].ffill()

# drop To Date rows and data column
df = df[~(df['all'] == 'To Date')].drop('data', 1)

# convert data to numeric
num_cols = ['year', 'all', 'deceased', 'living']
df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].applymap(locale.atoi)
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

     year    all  deceased  living     state
0    2018   7107      4394    2713       NaN
1    2017  16478     10286    6192       NaN
2    2016  15944      9971    5973       NaN
124  1990     85        49      36   Alabama
125  1989     80        57      23   Alabama
126  1988     86        68      18   Alabama
128  1989     16        12       4  Arkansas
129  1988     16        11       5  Arkansas
```